# MongoDB does not update record and promise keeps fail after multi or upsert is set to true

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have troubles with updating records in MongoDB (using mongoose). My code works but does not update record. See the code below:

```
edit(req, res, next) {
var WorkType = require('../models/WorkType');
WorkType.update({id: req.params.id}, {name: req.body.name}, false, false)
    .then(workType => {
        res.send(200, {message: 'Work Type updated successfully'});
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return next(err);
    })
}
```

This code **runs** but **does not update** info in database. POSTMAN request returns HTTP Status 200 OK with message:

> {
>      "message": "Work Type updated successfully"
>   }

When I change code to this

```
WorkType.update({id: req.params.id}, {name: req.body.name}, false, true)
```

I've got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

TypeError: callback.apply is not a function

If I change my code to this one:

```
WorkType.update({id: req.params.id}, {name: req.body.name}, true, false)
```

I've got error:

> TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'strict' in true

Can you please help me figure out where is problem or why promise is not working with 2nd code? Thanks a lot for your help!

---

WorkType.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var WorkTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
}
})

var WorkType = mongoose.model('WorkType', WorkTypeSchema);

module.exports = WorkType;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the `WorkType.update` (it can be the simple definition) to understand how it operates and why you're getting those errors, which currently appears as a wrong implementation or some typo in the code.

Comment: update() is a standard MongoDB function -> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: I'd check if the custom module `../models/WorkType` correctly implements the DB call.

Comment: I've edited my OP so you can check. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for the **update** method is:

```
Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback)
```

If you want to use promises then you should not pass a callback, so that Mongoose knows to return a promise instead. However, you are passing the value **true** for the callback argument here:

```
WorkType.update({ id: req.params.id }, { name: req.body.name }, false, true)
```

The **options** argument is expected to be of type *object* but you are passing the value **true** here:

```
WorkType.update({ id: req.params.id }, { name: req.body.name }, true, false)
```

You can pass an object as the options argument such as:

```
{ multi: true, upsert: true }
```

Passing **false** for both the *options* and *callback* arguments, as in your original code, should work as they should be ignored if not *truthy*.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I changed it and now Promises are working. But the field name doesn't change. 

I get HTTP Status 200 OK, but doesn't change :(

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Mongo sends ID as _id, so I changed it to WorkType.update({_id: req.params.id}, {name: req.body.name}, { multi: false, upsert: false }) and now it is working!